# Javascript pop up menu not shown in php

Tags: javascript, php

I have a website for check / search data. If we did not fill the form, and then click button search, there will a pop up menu that say "choose data". But, what happens is when we did not fill the form, and click button search, pop up menu not shown. this is my code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function EW_checkMyForm4(EW_this) {
    <?php
    if($_SESSION[dataname]==""){
    ?>
    if ( EW_hasValue(EW_this.x_data_names, "TEXT" ) && EW_hasValue(EW_this.x_sid_app_status, "SELECT" ) || EW_hasValue(EW_this.x_cust_name, "TEXT" ) || EW_hasValue(EW_this.x_id_card_no, "TEXT" ) || EW_hasValue(EW_this.x_initiation_date, "TEXT" ) || EW_hasValue(EW_this.x_Tanggal_Inisiasi_ke, "TEXT" ) || EW_hasValue(EW_this.x_cust_birthdate, "TEXT" ) || EW_hasValue(EW_this.x_engine_no, "TEXT" ) || EW_hasValue(EW_this.x_chassis_no, "TEXT" )) {

            return true;
    }else{

        if(!EW_hasValue(EW_this.x_data_names, "TEXT" )){
            alert('choose data !');
        } else {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
<?php }else{ ?>
if ( EW_hasValue(EW_this.x_sid_app_status, "SELECT" ) || EW_hasValue(EW_this.x_cust_name, "TEXT" ) || EW_hasValue(EW_this.x_id_card_no, "TEXT" ) || EW_hasValue(EW_this.x_initiation_date, "TEXT" ) || EW_hasValue(EW_this.x_Tanggal_Inisiasi_ke, "TEXT" ) || EW_hasValue(EW_this.x_cust_birthdate, "TEXT" ) || EW_hasValue(EW_this.x_engine_no, "TEXT" ) || EW_hasValue(EW_this.x_chassis_no, "TEXT" )) {
    return true;
}else{

    alert('fill at least one !');

    return false;
}
<?php } ?>

</script>
```

I'm using php 5.5.30. Can you help me to fix my problem? Thanks before..

Comment: This sounds more like a javascript issue, than a php issue. Have you looked at the source code to see what javascript code is printed? Can you show how you are calling `function EW_checkMyForm4(EW_this)` in your html?

Comment: that code is hard too read. have you considered another approach?

Comment: This might not be the best option but you can follow some steps to troubleshoot your code. 

 1. See your page source, which php condition worked.
 2. Use your browser's web console to see if there occurs an error while running you JavaScript code.

and you should also cross check your code. Because the closing parenthesis of function seems to be on the wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing a closing bracket on the javascript code in the else part of your PHP code. It's the one that is supposed to end the `EW_checkMyForm4` function.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your configured error reporting level, this:

```
if($_SESSION[dataname]==""){...
```

could be generating error messages like the following and breaking your code:

```
<b>Notice</b>:  Use of undefined constant dataname - assumed 'dataname'
```

Try adding quotes around the index:

```
if($_SESSION['dataname']==""){...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">

var dataname = '<?php echo $_SESSION[dataname]; ?>';

function EW_checkMyForm4(EW_this) {
    if (!dataname) {
        if ( EW_hasValue(EW_this.x_data_names, "TEXT" ) && EW_hasValue(EW_this.x_sid_app_status, "SELECT" ) || EW_hasValue(EW_this.x_cust_name, "TEXT" ) || EW_hasValue(EW_this.x_id_card_no, "TEXT" ) || EW_hasValue(EW_this.x_initiation_date, "TEXT" ) || EW_hasValue(EW_this.x_Tanggal_Inisiasi_ke, "TEXT" ) || EW_hasValue(EW_this.x_cust_birthdate, "TEXT" ) || EW_hasValue(EW_this.x_engine_no, "TEXT" ) || EW_hasValue(EW_this.x_chassis_no, "TEXT" )) {

                return true;
        
        }else{

            if(!EW_hasValue(EW_this.x_data_names, "TEXT" )){
                alert('choose data !');
            } else {
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    }
    else
        if ( EW_hasValue(EW_this.x_sid_app_status, "SELECT" ) || EW_hasValue(EW_this.x_cust_name, "TEXT" ) || EW_hasValue(EW_this.x_id_card_no, "TEXT" ) || EW_hasValue(EW_this.x_initiation_date, "TEXT" ) || EW_hasValue(EW_this.x_Tanggal_Inisiasi_ke, "TEXT" ) || EW_hasValue(EW_this.x_cust_birthdate, "TEXT" ) || EW_hasValue(EW_this.x_engine_no, "TEXT" ) || EW_hasValue(EW_this.x_chassis_no, "TEXT" )) {
            return true;
        }else{

            alert('fill at least one !');

            return false;
        }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to separate the second part of the condition with another parenthesis. Like this :

```
if ( EW_hasValue(EW_this.x_data_names, "TEXT" ) && (EW_hasValue(EW_this.x_sid_app_status, "SELECT" ) || EW_hasValue(EW_this.x_cust_name, "TEXT" ) || EW_hasValue(EW_this.x_id_card_no, "TEXT" ) || EW_hasValue(EW_this.x_initiation_date, "TEXT" ) || EW_hasValue(EW_this.x_Tanggal_Inisiasi_ke, "TEXT" ) || EW_hasValue(EW_this.x_cust_birthdate, "TEXT" ) || EW_hasValue(EW_this.x_engine_no, "TEXT" ) || EW_hasValue(EW_this.x_chassis_no, "TEXT" ))) {
```

**REASON**

If you dont have the brackets, your conditon `EW_hasValue(EW_this.x_data_names, "TEXT" ) && EW_hasValue(EW_this.x_sid_app_status, "SELECT" )` will be evaluated first and whatever that returns you have all other conditions with `||` operators. Which means your total condition expression will return true if any of the right side conditions returns `TRUE`.

**Another problem** I can see in your code, which may not be related to this issue, but it should create issues in other scenarios. You have this part of php code inside the js function `EW_checkMyForm4`

```
function EW_checkMyForm4(EW_this) {
<?php
if($_SESSION['dataname']==""){
?>
```

But the bracket is closed outside the js function. So, I think you should move this part above the function `EW_checkMyForm4` like this :

```
<?php
if($_SESSION['dataname']==""){
?>
function EW_checkMyForm4(EW_this) {
```

Comment: still not shown. hmm previously i use php 5.2.4, and the pop up menu works fine. but when i upgrade my php, pop menu not shown.